# CloudFront redirect on domain name, but domain name is not working with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have created CloudFront and also added custom SSL certificate to CloudFront. It has created CloulFront URL : http://di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net/

It is also redirect on https://extraship.com, but URL is not working.

I have checked image on https://di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net/img/banner.jpg and it is working fine with that. In CNAMEs, I have added www.extraship.com and In Origin Domain Name, it is www.extraship.com

In Route53, there are two Record Set created with "A - IPv4 Address"

1) extraship.com 
2) www.extraship.com

Both are pointing to 52.88.234.167

URL is not working, If I am pointing www.extraship.com to di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net cloudfront.

I have also tried to change CNAMEs and origin with extraship.com in CloulFront and in Route53 tried to point extraship.com to di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net cloudfront. But, it is not working.

Could anyone suggest me how it will work with https://www.extraship.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get 52.88.234.167 as an address for di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net from any DNSserver I use; I do get 54.230.48.{49,75,84,85,105,120,214,254} from the 4 apparently authoritative servers referred from the 4 delegated from GTLD for cloudfront.net, and similarly 54.230.38.several and 52.85.88.several from other servers; using curl to force-resolve www.extraship.com to a sample of these succeeds. However force-resolving extraship.com gets a handshake failure on hello, as does (expectedly) an atttempt with no SNI from `openssl s_client`

Comment: If I run openssl s_client -connect di0isyqnhnwcn.cloudfront.net:443 -servername extraship.com, I don't see that you have configured a custom certificate for your domain.  Have you followed the steps in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#cnames-and-https-procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in Route 53, you do create an A NAME, but you would select Alias and that will give you a dropdown of your cloudfront repository. You would select the cloudfront repository from the drop down and that should hook up the domain to your cloudfront repository.